# "Server Error Problem" in Node.js API (for android to web server request)

Tags: android, node.js, rest, api

"Server Error" in nodejs api (android to web server request)

I am a new node.js learner. I'm doing a project that user are registration by android application, and user details will go to web server. but when i send request to web server by API that time show "Server Error Problem". but when i send data by (postman row data) that time it works, but if i send by (postman form-data) that time it not work, and show "Server Error Problem".

In addition, I am using a shared linux Server supported by cpanel and CloudLinux.

```
-----------------------
index.js  file 
------------------------  
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cors = require('cors');

const verifyToken = require('./jwt/verify/verifytoken');
const mysql = require('mysql');
global.config = require('./jwt/config/config');
const extInfo = require('./info/extInfo');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: “abcd”,
    password: "123345",
    database: “xyz”
});

var point = 0;

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api/v1', require('./api/v1'));

------------------------------------
api file (code)
---------------------------

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql');


var error  = ["error", "error", "error"];

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: “abcd”,
    password: “12345”,
    database: “xyz”
});


router.get('/login?', (req , res) => {
    var studentdata = {
        A: req.query.a,
        B: req.query.b
    }  


    connection.query(`Select Student_id from student where Mobile = ${a} and Password = ${b}`, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error");
             res.send(error);
        } else if (result.length < 1){ 
            console.log("error");
             res.send(err);
        } 

        return res.send(result);

        let Student_id = result[0].Student_id ;

        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM B where A = ${A}`, (err1, result1, fields1) => {
            if(err1){
                 res.send(err1);
            } else if (result1.length < 1){
                  res.send(error);
            }
             res.send(result1);
         });
    });
});


router.post('/registration', (req , res) => {  

    let newStudent = { 
        a : req.body['a'],
        b: req.body.b,
        ....
        c: req.body.c
    }

    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM d1 where Mobile  = ${a}`, (err, result , fields) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send("Server Error");
        } else if (result.length > 0) {
            return res.send("wrong phone");
        }


        connection.query(`INSERT INTO d1 (Student_name, School , ..... , Password ) VALUES ('${newStudent.student_name}', ..... , '${newStudent.student_password}')`, (err1, result1, fields1) => {
            if(err1) {
                return res.send(error);
            } else if (result1.length > 0) {
                return res.send("wrong phone");
            }

            let insertId = result1.insertId;


  // Create Score table Account
             connection.query(`INSERT INTO d2( A ) VALUES ('${insertId}')`, (err2, result2, fields) => {

                if (err2) {
                    return res.send(err2);
                }

                return  res.send("Registration Successful");
            });
        })
    });

});


router.get('*', (req , res) => {
    res.send({"info" : "Nothing Found"});
});


module.exports = router ;
```

Comment: 1.what code are you using in android to call the api? 2. what is the result of select * from B? is B the name of a table? same question for select * from d1...

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan i am using Volley for calling API. B and d1 both are table name